# Directory not changing using exec comman in php

Tags: php, linux, exec, cd

Hi I am trying to make use of exec command and change the directory to execute a specific  command, but change directory is not working

```
when i execute exec('whoami'); i get proper output
```

when i execute following code

```
<?php

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
$var =  exec('cd /root/');
echo exec("pwd");

?>
```

my directory is not changing to root

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `chdir()` rather than `exec('cd /root/')`:

```
<?php

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
$var = chdir('/root/');
echo exec('pwd'); // Prints /root
```

This may not work if this is running on a website and the user the HTTP server is running as does not have access to `/root`.

The reason that `exec()` doesn't work is that it opens a new subprocess each time. Changing the current directory in one does not affect others spawned after.

Comment: Yes the webserver is running correct, Actully i want to execute some java commands using PHP exec, how can i do that?

Comment: @opensource-ios As stated above, use `chdir()` to change to the directory you want.

Comment: @opensource-ios Then I assume you do not have access to `/root`.

Comment: How can i give access to root? Is it something i could do though command prompt

Comment: @opensource-ios The whole point of `/root` is to only be accessible by superusers. Just create a folder somewhere else (perhaps inside `/usr/local/`) and give it world-readable permissions.

Comment: Thanks Phylogenesis, i did that and executed the follwouing code
<?php

// current directory


chdir('/usr/local');

// current directory
echo exec("java -version",$o);


print_r($o);
?>

but still its not working, it giving me  empty array